# Getting display resolution through Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was using javascript to obtain the my display resolution. The following code gave me the result of **1440 x 900** for my Macbook Pro

```
var screenWidth = screen.width;
var screenHeight = screen.height;
```

However, when I go check display setting of my Mac. It shows 2880 x 1800.
I'm wondering if I was on the wrong track on getting the resolution of a display?

[image: Macbook Pro display setting]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a Retina display. You can use `devicePixelRatio` to determine what the physical display size is.

```
var physicalScreenWidth = screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio;
var physicalScreenHeight = screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;
```

In your example, `devicePixelRatio` will be `2`

Comment: It works great for me. But just have a question, is that gonna work on all devices through different browsers?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio

Comment: This does not work on Chrome if you have the page zoomed in or out, with Ctrl+ or Ctrl-